# Magento 2 deployment script fro AWS codeDeploy

Tags: magento2, aws

I want to create a code deploy deployment plan for Magento 2. Code is on bitbucket repository and I need to know the correct deployment script fro Magento 2 which will deploy the latest changes on the server.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master

$ php bin/magento maintenance:enable

$ composer install --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader

$ rm -r var/cache/*
$ rm -r var/log/*
$ rm -r var/view_preprocessed/*
$ rm -r pub/static/_requirejs/*
$ rm -r pub/static/adminhtml/*
$ rm -r pub/static/frontend/*
$ rm -r generated/*

$ php bin/magento module:disable -c --all
$ php bin/magento module:enable --all --clear-static-content

$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento app:config:import --no-interaction
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated

$ php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

I am using these commands. Is this correct?

Comment: you have too many interchangeable commands. why you need to re-init all modules? i think `setup:upgrade` needs to go before everyting. then no need so many `rm -r` , then  just flush caches before with 3 commands, `service php-fpm restart` + `cache:flush` + `setup:upgrade`

Comment: also `mode:set production` generates, compile and deploy all code and static files

Comment: Thanks @MagenX, can you paste all commands in correct order?